# A Rust Type Mystery: Convert a function to a method, and calling function's signatures break compilation

Tags: methods, types, rust

A Mystery about Rust Types that I don't quite get.

I was recently refactoring code for a project and ran into a typing
mystery that has me puzzled, and I hope someone here can clarify what's
going on.

I've been writing a program to [implement the Seam Carving
algorithm](https://github.com/elfsternberg/pamseam-rs).  "Seam Carving"
is a way of reducing an image's dimensions automatically by finding, for
each pixel in a first row, the meandering path of pixels from
top-to-bottom or left-to-right that would do the least damage to the
image, and then removing that "seam."  The path is calculated from the
*energy* of each pixel: the distance between the colors of that pixel's
two neighbors is calculated, and then the seam with the *lowest total
delta* is identified.

So, Image → Energy Map → Seam → Reduced Image.

In memory, an image is a collection of rows concatenated together.
Scanning for a vertical seam means scanning *rows* (left and right
neighbors form the delta), but scanning for a horizontal seam means
scanning *columns*.  Adjacent pixels in columns are *not* adjacent in
memory, and this makes multi-threading with rayon or crossbeam
difficult.

The good news is that each *source* is read-only.  Generating the energy
map requires write access only to the energy map.  For columns, if I
could rotate the energy map I could multi-thread horizontal scanning.
That turns out to be easy, and all I need is a proxy object to map the
`(x, y)` to `(y, x)` when reading the image.  Let's call that proxy
object a `Pivot`.

Let me show some code (AviShaOne is the first seam carving algorithm, 
from Avidan & Shamir, "Seam Carving," 2007):

```
fn calculate_energy<I, P, S>(image: &I) -> TwoDimensionalMap<u32>
where
    I: GenericImageView<Pixel = P>,
    P: Pixel<Subpixel = S> + 'static,
    S: Primitive + 'static,
{
   ...
}

impl<'a, I, P, S> AviShaOne<'a, I, P, S>
where
    I: GenericImageView<Pixel = P>,
    P: Pixel<Subpixel = S> + 'static,
    S: Primitive + 'static,
{
    fn find_vertical_seam(&self) -> Vec<u32> {
        energy_to_seam(&calculate_energy(self.image))
    }
    fn find_horizontal_seam(&self) -> Vec<u32> {
        energy_to_seam(&calculate_energy(&Pivot::new(self.image)))
    }
}
```

Let me emphasize: The above code *works*.  The Pivot remaps the
coordinates, and now the internal functions can work with thread-capable
memory objects.

If I want to reduce an image by more than one seam, I have to run this
calculation repeatedly.  It would be nice if I could *cache* the energy
map.  (Since the seam meanders, and removing that seam would damage
seams that cross it, the column removed would be fairly large, but
it would still be less bad than recalculating it for *every seam*.)  I
want to add the energy map to the `struct`, and bring `calculate_energy`
into the the `impl`.

This is where things get weird:

```
impl<'a, I, P, S>  AviShaOne<'a, I, P, S>
where
    I: GenericImageView<Pixel = P>,
    P: Pixel<Subpixel = S> + 'static,
    S: Primitive + 'static,
{
    fn calculate_energy(&self, image: &I) -> TwoDimensionalMap<u32>
    {
        ...
    }

    fn find_horizontal_seam(&self) -> Vec<u32> {
        energy_to_seam(&self.calculate_energy(&Pivot::new(self.image)))
    }
}
```

All I did was move `calculate_energy` into the implementation.  No other
code was changed.  `Pivot` has the same type signature as `AviShaOne`,
as they're both handling these `GenericImageView` objects.  And now it
won't compile:

```
176 |         energy_to_seam(&self.calculate_energy(&Pivot::new(self.image)))
    |                                               ^^^^^^ expected type parameter, found struct `pivot::Pivot`
```

This is the mystery.  The functions are literally the same.  The type
signatures are, as far as I can tell, congruent, literally copied &
pasted for consistency. I have not added `energy` as a field yet! It worked fine when the function was just a
function, but now that it's a member of the implementation, the compiler
wants something else, but I have no idea what.

What does the compiler want?

Comment: What is the definition of `Pivot`?

Comment: It's a struct with the exact same signature and a full implementation of `I`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very important change, `calculate_energy` is no longer a generic function for all types `I` such that `I: Gener...` etc, etc. Instead it is a regular function expecting a very specific type `I`.

Which type `I`? Well, whichever `I` `AviShaOne` uses, which I'll assume is the same type as `self.image`. So calling `calculate_energy(self.image)` is fine.

However, `Pivot::new(self.image)` has an entirely different type, it is `Pivot`, not `I`. And since `calculate_energy` is no longer a generic function it can not deal with this.

Comment: That seems a bit counter-intuitive, as `Pivot` is an implementation of `I`.  It would have been nice if the error message had been more clear.  I understand why it's not working, and there's an acceptable work-around for it (keep the energy map in the main struct for caching, but pass it to a function for the actual mapping process), but that seems less OO-y than I expected.  (I know, Rust isn't an OO language, but sometimes `impl`s feel like it should be.)

Comment: @ElfSternberg No, you're still a bit confused. `Pivot` is not an implementation of `I` (which isn't even possible, `I` is a concrete type, not a trait), it is an implementation of `GenericImageView`. But `calculate_energy` expects `I`, not a `GenericImageView` when you made it non-generic. You can keep it inside the class but make it generic again.

Comment: That makes sense.  I'll see if I can genericize it, and maybe that'll help me understand the difference.